# Android call an encapsulated class containing a thread, infinite loop for refreshing UI not working

Tags: android, multithreading, encapsulation

The purpose of the android project is to read some data from hardware device and then update them in the UI. Now we need to encapsulate some code of receiving data by a background thread, and supply a function for other classes to get data from this encapsulated class. Down here is my code of this encapsulated class:

```
public class getDataFromUSB{
        private AtomicInteger usb_data = new AtomicInteger():
        private Random random;

        private Thread thread = new Thread(){
             @override
             public void run(){
                      while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                          synchronized(usb_data){
                               usb_data.set(read_usb());
                               usb_notify();
                          }
                      }
        };

        public void start(){
             thread.start();
        }

        public int get_data(){
             int ret_data=0;
             synchronized(usb_data){
                     try{
                            usb_data.wait();
                     }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                     ret_data=usb_data.get();
             }
             return ret_data;
        }
        public int read_usb(){
             return random.nextInt();
        }
}
```

In the main activity class, I want to keep getting the data of the USB in real time and then put it in a textview in the UI. So I call this class like the below:

```
final getDataFromUSB usb1=new getDataFromUSB();
usb1.start();
for(;;){
         myTextView.setText(String.valueof(usb1.get_data()));
}
```

However nothing appears in my myTextView. But when I test it with

```
for(;;){
         Log.d(TAG,"data="+usb1.get_data());
}
```

I can always get the real time value in my log. Anyone can help about this problem? Or if you have better ideas of encapsulating this kind of functionality and provide simple functions like 
get_data() which can give real time data, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for(;;)` you create an infinite loop, that never pauses and runs as fast as possible.

So other threads do not get (much) time schedules to actually do some of their own processing. The UI thread (that will repaint the `TextView`), has a low priority, so there is no way that the `TextView` is getting repainted..!

You might want to think about this a little more: the human eye has a refresh rate of 30 frames per second. You device also has a maximum refresh rate, which is much slower than the rate at which you are updating the `TextView`. So, it is common to update the UI with 60 fps. There is certainly no need to refresh the UI as fast as possible. (This is also better for your battery usage!)

So you need to use some kind of timing solution to reduce the refresh speed to 60 fps.

This also goes for the unlimited refresh rate of your `getDataFromUSB` thread! Grabbing USB at a faster rate than you (are going to) use makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

Have you read any about UI thread in android?

You are blocking UI thread running your loop. All UI drawings happens in UI thread. setText just sets property. it doesnt updates view. Never block UI thread as you did. Use Handler for example.

Comment: I would like to use handler too, but the requirement of our project is put all the multithreading codes in the encapsulated class, and provide simple functions like get_Data() for the user to call and get real time data. So I cannot find a way to do that with a handler in my encapsulated class and without any handler code in the main activity class.

Comment: then call get_Data functions from AsyncTask, for example. And post data to UI thead to update views.

Comment: Well. I've considered that too, but still we can't let AsyncTask to appear in the main activity class of the user. If I encapsulate AsyncTask in my class to call get_Data, how could I let the user to operate on UI with OnProgressUpdata() from their class?